Getting 415 Unsupported Media Type error when running tests in Spring, when it works when I manually test it
So I have this test set up
    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void testXml() throws Exception {
        String testXml = "<test><key1>value1</key1><key2>value2</key2></test>";

        result = mockMvc.perform(
                        post("/api/locationReportInput/testXML")
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                                .content(testXml))
                .andReturn();

        response = result.getResponse();

        Assertions.assertEquals(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED, response.getStatus());
    }

that tests this endpoint
    @PostMapping(value = "/testXML", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(@RequestBody final String testTest) {
        LOGGER.info(testTest);
        return ResponseEntity.created(null).build();
    }

and I am getting this error
12:16:04.765 [main] INFO  org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext - Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
12:16:04.765 [main] INFO  org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet ''
12:16:04.766 [main] INFO  org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 1 ms
12:16:04.838 [main] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/xml' is not supported]

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :201
Actual   :415
<Click to see difference>

but I can do a post request to this from Postman and get a 201 back. I am really lost on what to do here. Thanks.
I have tried changing the consumes type on the endpoint to all sorts of different values, and nothing works. I have also changed the media type on the contentType on the test request. I have set the mediatype for the endpoint to accept everything - yet I still get this error. I have created a copy of this endpoint and test but using JSON and the tests pass and everything works fine.
